# When converting a lxml.objectify.StringElement to a tuple, the individual elements are still strings

Tags: python, xml, kml

I have a lxml.objectify.StringElement from a kml parsing using pykml. 
Parsed as follows:

```
with open('btgdbgdgnh.kml') as f:
  documento = parser.parse(f).getroot().Document 

d = {}
for p in documento.Folder:
  d[p.name] = {}
  for place in p.Placemark:
        d[p.name][place.name] = []
        for pol in place.MultiGeometry.Polygon:
            d[p.name[place.name].append(pol.outerBoundaryIs.LinearRing.coordinates)
```

The output oof such parsing is as follows:

```
'\n                -0.458304,38.368177,0\n                -0.458486,38.368272,0\n                -0.458679,38.36836,0\n
```

After fighting with several kml libraries, I decided to do the hacky way and try to format it myself in order to feed it to create shapely polygons like so:

```
s='\n                -0.458304,38.368177,0\n      -0.458486,38.368272,0\n                -0.458679,38.36836,0\n

s = s.replace('0\n','0)|(')
s = s.replace('\n','(')
s = " ".join(s.split())
s = s.split('|')
```

Which renders this output:

```
  ['( -0.458304,38.368177,0)',
 '( -0.458486,38.368272,0)',
 '( -0.465878,38.368924,0)',
 '( -0.468405,38.368941,0)',
 '( -0.472423,38.369025,0)']
```

And I can't convert what is inside to a simple tuple. I tried ast library but seems deprecated(?), numpy array, which seemed the most "pythonic" like this:

```
results = np.fromstring(s, dtype=int, sep='|')
```

But returned an empty array. My solution from the beginning seems not a very good one, but is my first time using pykml, so this is the only way I could think and now I'm lost.
Any help would be apreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You...you have it right there

Comment: The code in the question is just a fragment. I should be able to copy, paste and run the code without changes. I cannot do that. Exactly how do you create the lxml.objectify.StringElement object? Where is the XML file? Can the problem be reproduced wth just lxml or do I need to install pykml?

Comment: How was it parsed o the XML cannot be shared nor redone. I thought it was clear from the first line that that was the problem

Comment: Why is the question tagged "xml"? What does this have to do with lxml.objectify?

Comment: Added it, without pii. Now that I look at the whole code, It maybe changeble, that parsing I mean

Comment: The exact wanted output is still not clear to me, but have you tried `ast.literal_eval()`? It is not deprecated. https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Comment: I tried ast, but seems to have a problem with all the spaces, as the coordinates are not in a tuple form

Answer (score 0):

Ended using list comprehension:

```
s=str(d['erveg']['dbgbtn']) 
s = " ".join(s.split())
po = [tuple(float(j) for j in i.split(",")) for i in s.split()[1:-2]]
```